# "length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent" on kmeans clustering

Tags: r, raster

I'm trying to perform a kmeans clustering on a group of rasters. Each raster has a different natural variable in a territory (e.g. precipitation) and I'm doing a kmeans to identify repeating spatial patterns across different rasters. The code line is very simple:

```
    kmncluster <- kmeans(na.omit(rasteraggregated), centers = 10, iter.max = 1000, nstart = 5, algorithm="Lloyd")
```

But it returns the error in the title.

This is my file:

```
    class      : RasterBrick 
    dimensions : 4821, 9069, 43721649, 12  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
    resolution : 100, 100  (x, y)
    extent     : 3909190, 4816090, 2404900, 2887000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
    crs        : +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
    source     : rasteraggregated.grd 
    names      : list of raster names
    min values :                  0.00,                  0.00,                  0.00,                  0.00,                   31.21,          0.00,                  0.00,         0.00,                  0.00,                    0.00,                      0.00,                  0.00 
    max values :                 97.79,                128.00,                100.00,                 99.00,                  100.00,        100.00,                128.00,       100.00,                100.00,                  100.00,                     97.90,                100.00
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm a newbie on R.
(the code doesn't actually say ' list of raster names ' btw)

Comment: Your example isn't reproducible, so I'll have to guess: the `kmeans` that you're calling is the one in the `stats` package.  It expects a matrix, not a `RasterBrick`.  You'll need to figure out how to extract a matrix from that object before you pass it to `kmeans()`.

Comment: Thank you, it was indeed a stupid mistake from my part. However before following your suggestion I'm now trying with unSuperClass from RStoolbox which should work with rasters.